# Difference between np.copy(X) and np.array(X)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
X = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
%timeit Y = np.copy(X)
%timeit Z = np.array(X)
X[0][0] = 12
print(X, id(X))
print(Y, id(Y))
print(Z, id(Z))
```

yields

```
1.86 µs ± 21.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
542 ns ± 7.98 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
[[12  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]] 140604052113808
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]] 140604052123360
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]] 140604052119600
```

Both creating a new instance with exactly the same values. I wonder what is the difference between the two.

Comment: For stuff like this, you really need to test with bigger inputs. Have you done that and still seen the same results?

Comment: For example, I start getting similar timings with `X = np.arange(120000).reshape(-1, 400)` but actually, that's also starting to feel a little too big before we might get to the point that `copy` wins